# Prevent click events from executing after a touch event

Tags: jquery, onclick, swipe, touch-event

Simply explained I have this code:

```
$(".button").swipe({
    swipe: function () {
        $("#output").append("You swiped!");
    }
}).click(function () {
    $("#output").append("You clicked!");
});
```

I want to be able to handle swipe on my element (TouchSwipe plugin) and clicks. The problem is that a touch is also a click. So if I swipe, I will first get "You swiped!" followed by a "You clicked!". Just clicking is ok.

Is it possible to stop the .click() from being executed if the .swipe() has already been executed? This, of course, has to work each time.

Comment: Have you tried Stop Propogation jQuery event? Link here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Yes, I also tried the stopImmediatePropogation. Still executes the clicked event also.

Comment: Have checked this example?:  http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Tap_vs_swipe.html

Comment: Can you supply us with a jsfiddle showing your implementation?

Comment: @Pro: I did not realize touchSwipe had a tap event. It did the trick btw :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Based on the implementation you supplied is with I'm guessing you are using the jQuery TouchSwipe plugin, correct?</strike>

Right, you noted you were using the jQuery TouchSwipe plugin, my bad :)

Instead of the jQuery click event (which does not take into account other plugin events) you should use the TouchSwipe tap event. This implementation helps distinguish the click from the swipe event and helps making sure only one gets executed.

```
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery('.button').swipe({
        tap: function()
        {
            alert('tapped');
        },
        swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount)
        {
            alert('swiped');            
        }
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bsmayh1q/